# How to make a UIScrollView longer?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to increase the scroll length of my UIScrollView. Not sure why this method isn't working:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+300)
```

Comment: Where are you calling this line of code?

Comment: Try calling it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method or in viewDidAppear().

Comment: If you are using storyboard, you can drag the height constraint of your content view to the view controller, then change the height by changing the constant (for example, self.verticalContentViewHeightConstraint.constant += 300)

Comment: Why are you trying to set the `scrollView.contentSize` instead of using auto-layout?

Comment: We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.con/help/mcve). Create a blank project and figure out what you need to add in order to manifest the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need empty space at the end of a scroll view you can achieve that by adding some content-insets like so:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 300, right: 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = insets
```